# How would I grep for a password file entry without using 'username'

Tags: grep, who

Can a who command be integrated to find the current logged in users password file entry?

Comment: While it might not be available everywhere, `users` might be a good alternative to `who` here, as it provides less information (you don't actually need more than usernames).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make a script like this:

```
for who_user in $(who|cut -f1 -d' '|uniq)
do
    getent passwd|grep ${who_user}
done
```

If you have enough permission you could look for the password at your shadow file like this:

```
for who_user in $(who|cut -f1 -d' '|uniq)
do
    cat /etc/passwd|grep ${who_user}
    cat /etc/shadow|grep ${who_user}
done
```

As mentioned by @John WH Smith no need of grep:

```
for who_user in $(who|cut -f1 -d' '|uniq)
do
    getent passwd ${who_user}
done
```

Thanks John

Comment: Note: `getent passwd` can be passed non-numeric keys in order to lookup specific usernames. You don't need to `grep`: `getent passwd ${who_user}`. See [`getent(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent) (your edit however is yet another useless use of `cat`: `grep` can handle filenames as arguments ; no need for the shadow search either)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
who | awk '{print $1}' | grep -f - /etc/passwd
```

`awk '{print $1}'` will output the usernames, which is passed to grep using the `-f -` option telling it to take the grep pattern from stdin. This will print out the `/etc/passwd` entry of the logged in users:

```
aliaa@host:~$ who
aliaa    tty7         2015-03-10 13:02
root     tty1         2015-03-10 18:19
aliaa    pts/0        2015-03-10 14:39 (:0)
aliaa@host:~$ who | awk '{print $1}' | grep -f - /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
aliaa:x:1000:1001:Alaa Ali,,,:/home/aliaa:/bin/bash
```